# I can't make the email markup for "Go-To Action" in email subject line

Tags: email, google-schemas

I'm having trouble with installing the email markup for "Go-To Action."

I've already verify the DKIM and SPF, which is the common reason of why this mark-up usually not working.

Can anybody check the code and let me know where I was wrong. I appreciate that a lot.

```
Delivered-To: itviec+jobrobot@itviec.com
Received: by 10.27.205.69 with SMTP id d66csp3167041wlg;
        Wed, 2 Dec 2015 20:28:11 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.129.38.3 with SMTP id m3mr5208082ywm.306.1449116891561;
        Wed, 02 Dec 2015 20:28:11 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <bounce-md_30049822.565fc4db.v1-17b05f83d90c4afc98d45e7150460630@mandrillapp.com>
Received: from mail133-26.atl131.mandrillapp.com (mail133-26.atl131.mandrillapp.com. [198.2.133.26])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id i184si3884636ywi.323.2015.12.02.20.28.11
        for <itviec+jobrobot@itviec.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 02 Dec 2015 20:28:11 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounce-md_30049822.565fc4db.v1-17b05f83d90c4afc98d45e7150460630@mandrillapp.com designates 198.2.133.26 as permitted sender) client-ip=198.2.133.26;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounce-md_30049822.565fc4db.v1-17b05f83d90c4afc98d45e7150460630@mandrillapp.com designates 198.2.133.26 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=bounce-md_30049822.565fc4db.v1-17b05f83d90c4afc98d45e7150460630@mandrillapp.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@itviec.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mandrillapp.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=mandrill; d=itviec.com;
 h=From:Subject:To:Message-Id:Date:MIME-Version:Content-Type; i=itviec+jobrobot@itviec.com;
 bh=9p1iDE8OCI5f1Cs1aLQ1TfefDaY=;
 b=WiDGxt547LeTZdT9OLDWHLDiYM4rDD5Ild9/g+w29AxZl8F8spWi51HOyZkrNcgXSXGTUN0MP1TX
   0uwcP05uVQDuINJUaWYkDC4uQrbciEITg8HbJHq3OH63lNW5/wDfOEROoVcPiACtNzKF3Te4aySZ
   /3tkJgYcmQfwUZtn2Ds=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; q=dns; s=mandrill; d=itviec.com;
 b=QFc22xXF+gAVDT1qJZyKWnPh+7YcY+yO08jZt87nQW0bUfQrfmF3X2E+lyhTK8JI7ksRtKgt526e
   ndasDLSw+siCqPelMNeDePkN7RLDNl5IXuEG6LnoWoBWzFOTYyH4vXGEOi0F+WmPD6aoR+RcUvxZ
   CAD28a/T4w0cKDLoVvw=;
Received: from pmta02.mandrill.prod.atl01.rsglab.com (127.0.0.1) by mail133-26.atl131.mandrillapp.com id hbv2dm1sar8o for <itviec+jobrobot@itviec.com>; Thu, 3 Dec 2015 04:28:11 +0000 (envelope-from <bounce-md_30049822.565fc4db.v1-17b05f83d90c4afc98d45e7150460630@mandrillapp.com>)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mandrillapp.com; 
 i=@mandrillapp.com; q=dns/txt; s=mandrill; t=1449116891; h=From : 
 Subject : To : Message-Id : Date : MIME-Version : Content-Type : From : 
 Subject : Date : X-Mandrill-User : List-Unsubscribe; 
 bh=r9dCb0UehKANmD5pcRPY5W2rPJcP5pLvGaFP5mqGDDM=; 
 b=Qp8iOYkcGl7UmlV7Yi6GCUhC4Frdqz9DGQIMiDMJJIOXJkxv+GUIzqb+6mdsFNFTMUACkP
 +71Ii8L/vQLef77Pp6ls5XedXP4N8faGRrnihyK84WUxAoN+Rcl8E86lhyCA2j1VAA8CmyAS
 tNNLHlxfsJCHjOw3GWL5q7VO9Su/A=
--_av-KsjmzauXlF-qEoqq3I296w
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div itemscope itemtype=3D"http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
  <div itemprop=3D"action" itemscope itemtype=3D"http://schema.org/ViewActi=
on">
    <link itemprop=3D"url" href=3D"http://itviec.com/search/java?utm_campai=
gn=3DJob+Robot&amp;utm_medium=3DJobRobot&amp;utm_source=3DEmail&amp;utm_ter=
m=3DView+all+your+jobs">
    <meta itemprop=3D"name" content=3D"Yes, View My Jobs">
  </div>
</div>


<table bgcolor=3D"#CCC" class=3D"mail" style=3D"margin-top: 10; font-family=
: 'Helvetica', san-serif; color: #444;" width=3D"100%">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <table align=3D"center" bgcolor=3D"white" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"=
0" class=3D"content" style=3D"margin-top: 20px; border-radius:7px" width=3D=
"550">
    <tr bgcolor=3D"#282828" class=3D"header" height=3D"75">
     <td style=3D"padding: 20px 30px; border-radius:7px 7px 0px 0px;">
      <a href=3D"itviec.com">
      <img alt=3D"ITviec" border=3D"0" height=3D"35px" src=3D"itviec.com/assets/l=
ogo-for-email-white-color.png" style=3D"float: left" width=3D"90px">
      </a>
      <div class=3D"title-nav-bar" style=3D"float: right; color: #FFF; margin-top=
: 8px; font-size: 18px">
Code Awesome
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I tested this code in [Email markup tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/) page, and the result is "no errors detected."

Comment: I think the reason why this does not work for you is because some of the content, specifically '=' is encoded as '=3D'

Answer (score 0):

@Dan Pham, I've tested your markup and was able to generate a action button. I'm assuming you haven't been whitelisted for the feature yet.

Is your email whitelisted for Gmail actions? If not, fill out this [registration form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1) to be enabled, you will also have to send a sample email with your microdata included.

You can find all the details on registering at the link below:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your `=3D` in your email. I don't know yet how to solve this but it should narrow your investigation.